# The remote server returned an error: (500) How can I resolve it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
try
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(argument);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path_apilog))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("State :" + state);
            sw.WriteLine("Output :" + result);
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path_apilog))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Exception Occurred :" + ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

What's wrong in this code when I run they gives error --

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: As the error message suggests, a "(500) Internal Server Error" is a problem on the server. You'll have to check your server logs and see what you can find. The problem isn't in the client code that you provide here.

Answer (score 0):

In web.config file, find the line `<compilation targetFramework="4.5">` and insert the debug property and set it to true, eg: `<compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true">`.

Comment: <configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup> 
</configuration>